How to have immutable shared object in python multiprocessing map
How can I let all of my worker processes share the same object that none of them mutate? For example, what is the cleanest way of writing a function that computes the dot product of an argument vector with a second vector that is the same for all processes. Naively, I would write something like this:
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def main():
    static_vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

    def f(v):
        return np.dot(v, static_vector)

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        results = p.map(f, [np.random.random((5,1)) for _ in range(10)])

    print(results)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

But this fails with the error AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.f'. For the sake of argument, computing the static vector takes some time and should not be done in each subprocess.

The main problem in your code is that you're passing the function f, which is not a top-level function and thus cannot be pickled. You should be able to refactor the code and move the function to the top level to make it work.

Yeah, but then I have to either 1. use a global variable for static_vector, which is both ugly and doesn't even work out of the box with multiprocessing, or 2. pass the vector as an argument to the function which is less ugly, but still feels a bit unnecessary since it's the same for all of the invocations of the function.

Since all child processes will be only reading that static_vector, not writing to it, it is called a global constant. Global constants are not ugly (when used correctly) and work perfectly fine, please stop this dogmatic approach.

It's constant for all of the sub-processes, but not for all purposes; it needs to be computed and can be different for different calls to the outer function. Here I called it main, but in the actual code it's of course a more complicated function, I just wrote a minimal example.

Seems like you are looking for multiprocessing.shared_memory.
Try this out!
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

def init_pool(shm_name,shape, dtype):
    global static_vector
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
    static_vector = np.ndarray(shape,dtype=dtype, buffer=existing_shm.buf)

def f(v):
    return np.dot(v,static_vector)

def main():
    static_vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=np.float64)
    static_vector_shape= static_vector.shape
    static_vector_dtype = static_vector.dtype

    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=static_vector.nbytes)
    shm_array = np.ndarray(static_vector_shape, dtype=static_vector_dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    np.copyto(shm_array, static_vector)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shm.name, static_vector_shape,static_vector_dtype)) as pool:
        vectors = [np.random.random(static_vector_shape) for _ in range(10)]
        results =pool.map(f, vectors)

    print(results)
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here I created shared memory block and copy static_vector into it.
Also I used initializer and initargs params of Pool to pass shared memory name and array metadata to each proces. In init_pool function each worker attaches to shared memory and reconstructs static_vector as a Numppy array

This is okay, but it seems very numpy array specific. What if instead I had a dict of values, or a class that I've defined?

@David there does exist a shared_memory.ShareableList but there are some strict limitations with that as well. The fact is multiprocessing is used to explicitly separate the memory space of processes. The true answer is to use threads instead, but the GIL restricts us from getting a performance benefit from that, so we must use workarounds (until removing the GIL is more supported at least).

@David For a sharable user-defined class you can create a managed custom class using multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager. For example, when you invoke multiprocessing.Manager() you get a  SyncManager object from which you can get sharable lists, dictionaries, etc. But each method you invoke on a managed class results in inter-process communication to implement and will be much slower than using shared memory. But using shared memory for user-defined classes is problematic (impossible?).
